# Calling a method on every instance of a class in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a class' method on every instance of that class.

Currently, I have all of my classes stored in an array, called `checkers[]`

I loop through every instance of the class `Checker()` using this for loop:

```
this.drawCheckers = function() {
    for(var checker in this.checkers) {
        checker.draw();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get the error:
`localcheckers.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: checker.draw is not a function`

How would I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `for..in` on an array. But if you do (and again, you shouldn't), you have to say `this.checkers[checker].draw()`, because that's how [`for..in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) work: your `checker` variable is the key/index, not the value.

Comment: Use [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead, that way `checker` will be the instance and not the index in the array

Answer (score 0):

In your for...in loop, the value stored in checker is not the property in this.checkers, but the property name.

What you need to do is access the property then call draw on it.

```
this.drawCheckers = function() 
{
    for(var checker in this.checkers) {
        this.checkers[checker].draw();
    }
}
```

See a working example here:
https://jsbin.com/fezixaboso/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

call `draw()` only if checker is an instance of Checker

```
this.drawCheckers = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.checkers.length; i++) {
        if(this.checkers[i] instanceof Checker)
            this.checkers[i].draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Its still wrong. `for..in` on an array puts the index in a variable, not the value.